# add extra parameters using mongoose transform on aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node.js. I am using mongoose, node.

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
});
schema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
tmp = ret;
tmp['abcd'] = 'abcd';
return tmp;
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('modelName', schema);
//my route.js
modelName.find({}, function (err, docs) {
docs.forEach(function(doc) {
console.log(doc);
console.log("doc['abcd'] is available");

});
});
modelName.aggregate({"$match":{"_id":{"$ne":0}}} function (err, docs) {
docs.forEach(function(doc) {
console.log(doc);
console.log("doc['abcd'] is not available");
});
});
```

I am using above code to add extra parameters while rendering. But when i use aggregate, it is not working. Is there any way to add extra parameters while rendering even on aggregate also? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code? It's not clear what you are doing. What parameters are you talking about?

Comment: I meant by removing parameters such as  _id  and adding new one.